# What is navigating backwards through the Alt-Tab UI called?

Tags: navigation, terminology

In Windows, you can use <kbd>Alt+tab</kbd> to navigate through windows in "Most recently used" order (MRU order). Subsequent <kbd>tab</kbd> keypresses will continue to move you through the MRU ordering, until <kbd>alt</kbd> is released.

If you instead press <kbd>Alt+shift+tab</kbd>, the UI will navigate *backwards* through that list. However, what's that action called? The action here of navigating backwards through the MRU list.

It's not the "next most recently used window", but it's also not the "previously most recently used window", nor is it the "last most recently used window" - those are all the same thing, the window you just came from.

My use case here: We're using `nextTab` to select the next tab (in-order), and `prevTab` to get at the previous in-order tab, but suddenly those names don't apply so well when we're talking about MRU navigation between tabs. `nextMRUTab` and `prevMRUTab` are the *semantically* same thing

Answer (score 1):

**Borrow the *browser history* paradigm—these movements take the user "back" and "forward" in time.**

Most Recently Used tabs ("MRU", as you say) represent the users' viewing history, sorted by most recently visited. In a web browser (or file explorer, or ...), a user can navigate *back* in time, or *forward* to catch back up to where they were.

In the same way, you could navigate to the `backMRUTab` or `forwardMRUTab`.